# Why am I getting so many errors?

Tags: python, debugging

Yes, I know my code is messy, and terrible, and like 20 lines are just variable with the value of 0, and I know basically nothing about python and am going way out of my element but I need some answers as to how any why when I click play (on pycharm) I get THIS ERROR: File "C:\Users\dank_\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 184
elif atck1 == "Dart":
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

I dont get it... I also have a red warning that says "Indent Expected: 48" someone explain please, thanks in advance.

```
    import time
import random
FN = 0
Cha1 = 0
Cha2 = 0
Cha3 = 0
Cha4 = 0
SA1 = 0
cSA1 = 0
cSA2 = 0
cSA3 = 0
cSA4 = 0
cSA1a = 0
cSA2a = 0
cSA3a = 0
cSA4a = 0
character = 0
pl1 = 100
pl2 = 100
pl2a = 10
pl1a = 10
pl1w = 20
pl2w = 20
pl2f = 20
pl1f = 20
ph1 = 0
ph2 = 0
pd1 = 0
fd1 = 0
wd1 = 0
rd1 = 0
pd2 = 0
fd2 = 0
wd2 = 0
rd2 = 0
DPH = 0
DPH1 = 0
DPH2 = 0
DPH3 = 0
DPH4 = 0
HA = 70

tcharacter = ""
tcharacter2 = ""
while FN == 0:
    sad = input("Roll the dice!: ")
    if sad != "no":
    FN = + 1
    if sad == "no":
       JJJ = random.randint(1, 4)
       if JJJ == 1:
           print("Come on, just do it. ")
       elif JJJ == 2:
           print("Really? come on")
       elif JJJ == 3:
           print("I said roll the dice")

char1 = random.randint(1, 4)

if char1 == 1:
    print("You pulled...")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("The Danger Ranger")
    Cha1 = + 1
    cSA1 = + 1
elif char1 == 2:
    print("You pulled...")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("Fire Flame Man")
    Cha2 = + 1
    cSA2 = + 1
elif char1 == 3:
    print("You pulled...")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("Water Winkle Wanderer")
    Cha3 = + 1
    cSA3 = + 1
elif char1 == 4:
    print("You pulled...")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("Poisoned Platter Person")
    Cha4 = + 1
    cSA4 = + 1
ph1 = + 1






while SA1 == 0:
   SA1 = input("Roll the dice!: ")
   if SA1 != "no":
    SA1 =+ 1
   if SA1 == "no":
       JJJ = random.randint(1, 4)
       if JJJ == 1:
           print("Come on, just do it. ")
       elif JJJ == 2:
           print("Really? come on")
       elif JJJ == 3:
           print("I said roll the dice")

char2 = random.randint(1, 4)

if char2 == 1:
    if Cha1 < 1:
        print("You pulled...")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("The Danger Ranger")
        Cha1 = + 1
        cSA1a = + 1
elif char2 == 2:
    if Cha2 < 1:
        print("You pulled...")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Fire Flame Man")
        Cha2 = + 1
        cSA2a = + 1
elif char2 == 3:
    if Cha3 < 1:
        print("You pulled...")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Water Winkle Wanderer")
        Cha3 = + 1
        cSA3a = + 1
elif char2 == 4:
    if Cha4 < 1:
        print("You pulled...")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Poisoned Platter Person")
        Cha4 = + 1
        cSA4a = + 1
ph2 = + 1

if cSA1 == 1:
    tcharacter = "The Danger Ranger"
elif cSA2 == 1:
    tcharacter = "Fire Flame Man"
elif cSA3 == 1:
    tcharacter = "Water Winkle Wanderer"
elif cSA4 == 1:
    tcharacter = "Poisoned Platter Person"

print("Player 1, your character is", tcharacter, "Your attacks are...")
time.sleep(1)

if tcharacter == "The Danger Ranger":
    print("Six shooter, 6 quick shots of random damage, to use, say \"Six\"... Oversized Hat, 1 Slow attack based on your health, to use, say \"Hat\"... Lever action, 1 quick high damage attack, to use, say \"Bang\"")
elif tcharacter == "Fire Flame Man":
    print("Fireball, 1 quick attack on random damage, to use, say \"Fire\"... Oxygen, adds damage to your next attack and increases defense, to use, say \"Oxy\"... Falling Debris, 10 quick attacks on random damage, to use, say \"Fall\"")
elif tcharacter == "Water Winkle Wanderer":
    print("Tsunami, 1 massive slow attack, to use, say \"Wave\"... Flash Flood, 1 Instant low damage attack, to use, say \"Flood\" ")
elif tcharacter == "Poisoned Platter Person":
    print("Spoiled Bread, 1 Instant high damage attack, high chance to miss, to use, say \"Bread\"... Poisoned Dart, 1 quick medium damage attack, to use, say \"Dart\"... Tainted Wine, 1 Instant no damage attack, lowers your opponents defens permanantly, to use, say \"Wine\" ")


if cSA1a == 1:
    tcharacter2 = "The Danger Ranger"
elif cSA2a == 1:
    tcharacter2 = "Fire Flame Man"
elif cSA3a == 1:
    tcharacter2 = "Water Winkle Wanderer"
elif cSA4a == 1:
    tcharacter2 = "Poisoned Platter Person"

print("Player 2, your character is", tcharacter2, "Your attacks are...")

if tcharacter2 == "The Danger Ranger":
    print("Six shooter, 6 quick shots of random damage, to use, say \"Six\"... Oversized Hat, 1 Slow attack based on your health, to use, say \"Hat\"... Lever action, 1 quick high damage attack, to use, say \"Bang\"")
elif tcharacter2 == "Fire Flame Man":
    print("Fireball, 1 quick attack on random damage, to use, say \"Fire\"... Oxygen, adds damage to your next attack and increases defense, to use, say \"Oxy\"... Falling Debris, 10 quick attacks on random damage, to use, say \"Fall\"")
elif tcharacter2 == "Water Winkle Wanderer":
    print("Tsunami, 1 massive slow attack, to use, say \"Wave\"... Flash Flood, 1 Instant low damage attack, to use, say \"Flood\" ")
elif tcharacter2 == "Poisoned Platter Person":
    print("Spoiled Bread, 1 Instant high damage attack, high chance to miss, to use, say \"Bread\"... Poisoned Dart, 1 quick medium damage attack, to use, say \"Dart\"... Tainted Wine, 1 Instant no damage attack, lowers your opponents defense permanantly, to use, say \"Wine\" ")


atck1 = input("What attack do you use Player 1?")

if pd1 >= 1:
    if atck1 == "Bread":
        PA1 = random.randint(0, 8)
        HA = + PA1
        JL1 = random.randint(1, 3)
        if JL1 == 1:
            pl2 = - PA1
            print("Hit! Player 2 is now at", pl2, "health")
            if PA1 >= 5:
                print("Critical Hit!")
        else:
            pl1a = - 10
            print("Miss!")

elif atck1 == "Wine":
            PA2 = random.randint(1, 6)
            if PA2 == 1:
                pl1a = - 10
                print("Miss!")
            else:
                pl2a = - 15
                print("Hit! Opponent's defense now at", pl2a)

elif atck1 == "Dart":
        PA3 = random.randint(1, 10)
        if PA3 == 1:
              pl1a = - 10
              pl1 = - 1
              print("Ouch! You accidentally poked yourself with the dart! ")

        else:
            H1 = 10
            pl2a = + DPH
            DPH /= 4
            DPH = - H1
            H1 = - pl2
            print("Hit!")

elif wd1 >= 1:
    if atck1 == "Wave":
        H2 = random.randint(0, 7)
        JL2 = random.randint(1, 5)
        if JL2 == 1:
            H3 = 70
            pl2a = + DPH1
            DPH1 /= 4
            DPH1 = - H3
            H3 = - pl2
            print("Hit! Player 2 is now at", pl2, "health")
            if H2 >= 5:
                print("Critical Hit!")
        else:
            pl1a =- 10
            print("Miss!")

    elif atck1 == "Flood":
        H4 = 14
        pl2a = + DPH2
        DPH2 /= 4
        DPH2 = - H4
        H1 = - pl2
        pl2 = - H4
        print("Oof, Player 2 is now at", pl2, "health" )

elif fd1 >= 1:
    print("testpls")

elif rd1 >= 1:
    print("a")
```

Comment: Please read [mre]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Extra Indent at line 1

```
    import time
import random
```

Missing Indent at line 48

```
while FN == 0:
sad = input("Roll the dice!: ")
if sad != "no":
FN = + 1 #here should have indent
if sad == "no":
   JJJ = random.randint(1, 4)
   if JJJ == 1:
       print("Come on, just do it. ")
   elif JJJ == 2:
       print("Really? come on")
   elif JJJ == 3:
       print("I said roll the dice")
```

Comment: It stopped the red mark but when I try to run it, it still prints the original error message :(

Comment: I still get the File "C:\Users\dank_\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 184
    elif atck1 == "Dart":
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block when I run the code

Comment: At line 184 `HA = + PA1`  its either missing a value at the front or the `+` should not be there.

Comment: Alright thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your indentation problem at line 48.

```
import time
import random
FN = 0
Cha1 = 0
Cha2 = 0
Cha3 = 0
Cha4 = 0
SA1 = 0
cSA1 = 0
cSA2 = 0
cSA3 = 0
cSA4 = 0
cSA1a = 0
cSA2a = 0
cSA3a = 0
cSA4a = 0
character = 0
pl1 = 100
pl2 = 100
pl2a = 10
pl1a = 10
pl1w = 20
pl2w = 20
pl2f = 20
pl1f = 20
ph1 = 0
ph2 = 0
pd1 = 0
fd1 = 0
wd1 = 0
rd1 = 0
pd2 = 0
fd2 = 0
wd2 = 0
rd2 = 0
DPH = 0
DPH1 = 0
DPH2 = 0
DPH3 = 0
DPH4 = 0
HA = 70

tcharacter = ""
tcharacter2 = ""
while FN == 0:
    sad = input("Roll the dice!: ")
    if sad != "no":
        FN = + 1
    if sad == "no":
       JJJ = random.randint(1, 4)
       if JJJ == 1:
           print("Come on, just do it. ")
       elif JJJ == 2:
           print("Really? come on")
       elif JJJ == 3:
           print("I said roll the dice")

char1 = random.randint(1, 4)

if char1 == 1:
    print("You pulled...")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("The Danger Ranger")
    Cha1 = + 1
    cSA1 = + 1
elif char1 == 2:
    print("You pulled...")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("Fire Flame Man")
    Cha2 = + 1
    cSA2 = + 1
elif char1 == 3:
    print("You pulled...")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("Water Winkle Wanderer")
    Cha3 = + 1
    cSA3 = + 1
elif char1 == 4:
    print("You pulled...")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("Poisoned Platter Person")
    Cha4 = + 1
    cSA4 = + 1
ph1 = + 1






while SA1 == 0:
   SA1 = input("Roll the dice!: ")
   if SA1 != "no":
    SA1 =+ 1
   if SA1 == "no":
       JJJ = random.randint(1, 4)
       if JJJ == 1:
           print("Come on, just do it. ")
       elif JJJ == 2:
           print("Really? come on")
       elif JJJ == 3:
           print("I said roll the dice")

char2 = random.randint(1, 4)

if char2 == 1:
    if Cha1 < 1:
        print("You pulled...")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("The Danger Ranger")
        Cha1 = + 1
        cSA1a = + 1
elif char2 == 2:
    if Cha2 < 1:
        print("You pulled...")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Fire Flame Man")
        Cha2 = + 1
        cSA2a = + 1
elif char2 == 3:
    if Cha3 < 1:
        print("You pulled...")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Water Winkle Wanderer")
        Cha3 = + 1
        cSA3a = + 1
elif char2 == 4:
    if Cha4 < 1:
        print("You pulled...")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Poisoned Platter Person")
        Cha4 = + 1
        cSA4a = + 1
ph2 = + 1

if cSA1 == 1:
    tcharacter = "The Danger Ranger"
elif cSA2 == 1:
    tcharacter = "Fire Flame Man"
elif cSA3 == 1:
    tcharacter = "Water Winkle Wanderer"
elif cSA4 == 1:
    tcharacter = "Poisoned Platter Person"

print("Player 1, your character is", tcharacter, "Your attacks are...")
time.sleep(1)

if tcharacter == "The Danger Ranger":
    print("Six shooter, 6 quick shots of random damage, to use, say \"Six\"... Oversized Hat, 1 Slow attack based on your health, to use, say \"Hat\"... Lever action, 1 quick high damage attack, to use, say \"Bang\"")
elif tcharacter == "Fire Flame Man":
    print("Fireball, 1 quick attack on random damage, to use, say \"Fire\"... Oxygen, adds damage to your next attack and increases defense, to use, say \"Oxy\"... Falling Debris, 10 quick attacks on random damage, to use, say \"Fall\"")
elif tcharacter == "Water Winkle Wanderer":
    print("Tsunami, 1 massive slow attack, to use, say \"Wave\"... Flash Flood, 1 Instant low damage attack, to use, say \"Flood\" ")
elif tcharacter == "Poisoned Platter Person":
    print("Spoiled Bread, 1 Instant high damage attack, high chance to miss, to use, say \"Bread\"... Poisoned Dart, 1 quick medium damage attack, to use, say \"Dart\"... Tainted Wine, 1 Instant no damage attack, lowers your opponents defens permanantly, to use, say \"Wine\" ")


if cSA1a == 1:
    tcharacter2 = "The Danger Ranger"
elif cSA2a == 1:
    tcharacter2 = "Fire Flame Man"
elif cSA3a == 1:
    tcharacter2 = "Water Winkle Wanderer"
elif cSA4a == 1:
    tcharacter2 = "Poisoned Platter Person"

print("Player 2, your character is", tcharacter2, "Your attacks are...")

if tcharacter2 == "The Danger Ranger":
    print("Six shooter, 6 quick shots of random damage, to use, say \"Six\"... Oversized Hat, 1 Slow attack based on your health, to use, say \"Hat\"... Lever action, 1 quick high damage attack, to use, say \"Bang\"")
elif tcharacter2 == "Fire Flame Man":
    print("Fireball, 1 quick attack on random damage, to use, say \"Fire\"... Oxygen, adds damage to your next attack and increases defense, to use, say \"Oxy\"... Falling Debris, 10 quick attacks on random damage, to use, say \"Fall\"")
elif tcharacter2 == "Water Winkle Wanderer":
    print("Tsunami, 1 massive slow attack, to use, say \"Wave\"... Flash Flood, 1 Instant low damage attack, to use, say \"Flood\" ")
elif tcharacter2 == "Poisoned Platter Person":
    print("Spoiled Bread, 1 Instant high damage attack, high chance to miss, to use, say \"Bread\"... Poisoned Dart, 1 quick medium damage attack, to use, say \"Dart\"... Tainted Wine, 1 Instant no damage attack, lowers your opponents defense permanantly, to use, say \"Wine\" ")


atck1 = input("What attack do you use Player 1?")

if pd1 >= 1:
    if atck1 == "Bread":
        PA1 = random.randint(0, 8)
        HA = + PA1
        JL1 = random.randint(1, 3)
        if JL1 == 1:
            pl2 = - PA1
            print("Hit! Player 2 is now at", pl2, "health")
            if PA1 >= 5:
                print("Critical Hit!")
        else:
            pl1a = - 10
            print("Miss!")

elif atck1 == "Wine":
            PA2 = random.randint(1, 6)
            if PA2 == 1:
                pl1a = - 10
                print("Miss!")
            else:
                pl2a = - 15
                print("Hit! Opponent's defense now at", pl2a)

elif atck1 == "Dart":
        PA3 = random.randint(1, 10)
        if PA3 == 1:
              pl1a = - 10
              pl1 = - 1
              print("Ouch! You accidentally poked yourself with the dart! ")

        else:
            H1 = 10
            pl2a = + DPH
            DPH /= 4
            DPH = - H1
            H1 = - pl2
            print("Hit!")

elif wd1 >= 1:
    if atck1 == "Wave":
        H2 = random.randint(0, 7)
        JL2 = random.randint(1, 5)
        if JL2 == 1:
            H3 = 70
            pl2a = + DPH1
            DPH1 /= 4
            DPH1 = - H3
            H3 = - pl2
            print("Hit! Player 2 is now at", pl2, "health")
            if H2 >= 5:
                print("Critical Hit!")
        else:
            pl1a =- 10
            print("Miss!")

    elif atck1 == "Flood":
        H4 = 14
        pl2a = + DPH2
        DPH2 /= 4
        DPH2 = - H4
        H1 = - pl2
        pl2 = - H4
        print("Oof, Player 2 is now at", pl2, "health" )

elif fd1 >= 1:
    print("testpls")

elif rd1 >= 1:
    print("a")
```